# php send and catch data in url without any variable name

Tags: php

passing data between pages in php have ways like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` etc. But if we are to send data without any variable in php, there is a way which I seem to have forgotten.

For example , let a sample url be  : www.mysite.com?123

Is it possible to catch the value 123 from the corresponding php page ?

any use of `$_SERVER` here?

Comment: You can do with $_SESSION by setting value to it and get on other pages on which you want.

Comment: I wanted in the url way.

Comment: well the question is why do you want to do that?pretty url-s? if yes, take a look at mod_rewrite.

Comment: just wanted to know the rule.

Comment: Ohk than u can use $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] .You will get the url .And from that u can get your value from there.But here u have to extract it from url ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it using:

```
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
```

This url: `www.mysite.com?123` will provide `123` into `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`.

But be careful, if your url is like`www.mysite.com?123&re=789`, `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` will be `123&re=789`. It catch every thingg after the `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out with:

```
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ you think this might solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that browsers default to HTTP GET, so the variables would be accessible by `$_GET`.

If you are trying to get "123", then `key($_GET)` should suffice. However if there are more parameters, consider looping through the keys of the `$_GET` array.

```
echo 'First $_GET variable: ' . key($_GET);

echo "All the $_GET variables:";
print_r( array_keys($_GET) );
```

Comment: `$_GET` is an associative array. which index to be used for the array ?

Comment: The index would be `123` in your case. Or if your URL was `http://example.com/?123=abc`, then the index would still be `123`, with a value of `abc`.

Comment: Yes, but the index will always be a string, so `$_GET['123']`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to further explain how the array is working.

Comment: It worked perfectly fine: http://swag.3owl.com/testGet.php?123 (This link will expire shortly)

Comment: Please look at the last four lines of the link that I provided.

Answer (score 0):

easy one, don't forget the $_GET is an array....

so a url like

*www.mysite.com?123*

```
$getArrayKeys = array_keys($_GET);

$firstValue = $getArrayKeys[0];  //work with the first param.

var_dump($getArrayKeys); //display all
```

**OUTPUT**

> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "123" }

however you're limiting yourself to a single param here... what happens when you need to pass a second param and they are not in the same order?

Comment: just trying to know the answer for a single param

Comment: how to get only the value `123` ?

Comment: then you use the above code.
`$getArrayKeys = array_keys($_GET);
$firstValue = $getArrayKeys[0];
echo $firstValue`